# How can I check to see if the browser has been opened yet in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make each of the tests in my class independent of each other but also be able to run together. Right now I have it set up like this

public class MASTER {

```
@AfterSuite
public static void close() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    Browser.driver.quit();
}

@Test(enabled=true, priority=0)
public void initiate(){
    Browser.openBrowser("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/");
}

@Test(enabled=true, priority=1)
public void addProductToCart(){

    Browser.isURLCorrect("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/");
    commonRepeats.goToCart("chocolates",5);

}

@Test(enabled=true, priority=2)
public void emptyCart(){

    Browser.isURLCorrect("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/");
    commonRepeats.goToCart("chocolates", 5);
    cart.emptyCart();

}

@Test(enabled=true, priority=3)
public void comprar(){
    Browser.isURLCorrect("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/");
    commonRepeats.goToProduct("chocolates", 5);
    product.comprar();
}

@Test(enabled=true, priority=4)
public void schedule(){
    Browser.isURLCorrect("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/");
    commonRepeats.goToProduct("chocolates", 5);
    product.checkSchedule();
}
```

}

public class Browser {

```
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void openBrowser(String URL){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static void goHome(){
    driver.navigate().to("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/medellin/");
}

public static void isURLCorrect(String URL){

    String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    if (currentURL==URL)
        System.out.println("correct URL");
    else
        driver.navigate().to(URL);

}
```

}

public class commonRepeats {

```
public static void goToCart(String Category, int nthITEM){
    home.chooseCategory(Category);
    category.chooseItem(nthITEM);
    product.addToCart();
}

public static void goToProduct(String Category, int nthITEM){
    home.chooseCategory(Category);
    category.chooseItem(nthITEM);
}
```

}

I have been trying to find some sort of way to get a boolean value to use in an if statement to test before each test so that if it returned false (indicating the browser has not been opened and I am trying to individually run this test out of all of them) I could have it open the browser from where the last test would have left it so it can continue as it should.

I tried using driver.toString() to see if it returned null but I just kept getting nullpointerexception

Comment: Why `driver.toString()`??? And where it is in your provided code??? And FYI `.toString()` will throw null exception if `driver` is null, just check `driver == null`..

Comment: Where is the driver created (e.g. show the code)? What is openBrowser(string)? Is that a wrapper you have custom made?

Comment: It is in another class but i deleted it because it was not working, this is just one of my classes with code.

Comment: I will edit my post with the rest of the code, my apologies

Comment: Just edited it! the rest of my code (which I didn't add because of length) is simply identifying objects on several pages of the website I am testing on.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur driver==null worked, thank you so much!!!

Comment: If you use JUnit, you could use `@FixMethodOrder` (example: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-execution-order), but making tests depend on order of execution is a bad practice. Also you don't verify anything, so your tests will pass even if they are failing.